# How to flag old vs new accounts for the activities based on the Fiscal year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple columns but below is the sample of few necessary columns. I want to figure out where the given account is New/Old for the given fiscal year based on the account started date. Here is the sample data:

Account ID  Account ID  BU  CC  Start Date  Activity Dates  Sales   Budget Year
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    3/10/2018   10  FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    4/9/2018    35  FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    4/24/2018   60  FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    5/9/2018    85  FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    5/24/2018   110 FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    6/8/2018    135 FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    6/23/2018   160 FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    7/8/2018    185 FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/3/2018    7/23/2018   210 FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/4/2018    8/7/2018    235 FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/5/2018    8/22/2018   260 FY2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/6/2018    9/6/2018    285 FY2019
1   offset  10  1000    2/7/2018    9/21/2018   310 FY2019
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   1/1/2020    335 FY2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   2/5/2020    360 FY2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   3/11/2020   385 FY2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   4/15/2020   410 FY2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   5/20/2020   435 FY2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   6/24/2020   460 FY2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   7/29/2020   485 FY2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   9/2/2020    510 FY2021
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   10/7/2020   535 FY2021

Our company budget year cycle is different than the calendar year. Budget year starts in September and runs to August of the next year. I want to figure out the new/old based on the account started date and considering still new for the fiscal year before the 5 months. Wanted data sample looks like:

```
Account ID  Account Name    Business Unit   Costco Center   Account Start Date  Actual Activity Dates   Sales   Budget Year New/Old Account Budget Begin Date
```

I want to flag the activities for the accounts New/Account basedon the account started. If he account starts just before 5 months of the new fiscal period then I want to flag it as the new for the next fiscal year. Say, account started in 04/01/2019 and the fiscal year for account start is FY2019 but I want to flag this as new for FY2020. For the activities which takes place in FY2019 and FY2020, I want the flag to be new and for activities after FY 2020 should be old.

Account ID  Account ID  BU  CC  Start Date  Activity Dates  Sales   Budget Year New/Old/Other Flag  Flag Start Date (Activities for the Fiscal Year should be 5 months before the actual Fiscal year starts)    Flag End Date
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    3/10/2018   10  FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    4/9/2018    35  FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    4/24/2018   60  FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    5/9/2018    85  FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    5/24/2018   110 FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    6/8/2018    135 FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    6/23/2018   160 FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/2/2018    7/8/2018    185 FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/3/2018    7/23/2018   210 FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/4/2018    8/7/2018    235 FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/5/2018    8/22/2018   260 FY2018  New 4/1/2017    8/31/2018
1   offset  10  1000    2/6/2018    9/6/2018    285 FY2019  old 4/1/2018    8/31/2019
1   offset  10  1000    2/7/2018    9/21/2018   310 FY2019  old 4/1/2018    8/31/2019
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   1/1/2020    335 FY2020  New 4/1/2019    8/31/2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   2/5/2020    360 FY2020  New 4/1/2019    8/31/2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   3/11/2020   385 FY2020  New 4/1/2019    8/31/2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   4/15/2020   410 FY2020  New 4/1/2019    8/31/2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   5/20/2020   435 FY2020  New 4/1/2019    8/31/2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   6/24/2020   460 FY2020  New 4/1/2019    8/31/2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   7/29/2020   485 FY2020  New 4/1/2019    8/31/2020
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   9/2/2020    510 FY2021  old 4/1/2020    8/31/2021
1   offset  20  1000    12/1/2019   10/7/2020   535 FY2021  old 4/1/2020    8/31/2021

For every given activities of the account, i want to see whether the new or old catalog was making profit. It is for the analysis to see how much it is making when it is new for the activities when the account is new Vs old.

Comment: *"enter image description here"* doesn't tell us anything about your data, however, don't post images anyway; post data in a **consumable** format. Preferably DDL and DML statements, however, if not then well formatted tabular formatted `text`. Also, don't forget to show us what you've tried so far and explain why it didn't work. Asking a question is also important, as you haven't asked one here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fiscal year for an account by either adding 4 months or subtracting 8 months and then extracting the year (you don't say if Sep 2000 - Aug 2001 is FY 2000 or FY 2001).

The logic looks like:

```
select year(dateadd(month, 4, startdate)) as fy
```

Comment: But I need to know for every activity through out the years, I want to flag whether the account is new or old at given time based on the account release date and which Fiscal year it was started.

Comment: Which is why we need sample data, @SQLBeginner , which you've omitted ((links to) images don't count).